# I am not able to fetch/retrieve all the results from keepa API

Tags: keep-alive

I have integrated [keepa api](https://www.ecompath.com/articles/keepa-amazon-price-tracker) with google Gsuite. I put the per-page limit at 10,000 in the payload and tried to iterate the page. On page 0 I got the 10,000 records but when I tried to iterate the page to 1 and 2, I got the error that page and page limit is invalid. My question is how can I retrieve all the the data shown in response field `totalResults` (which in my case is around half million)?

Here is my payload pattern in postman
[image: postman screenshot]

Keepa also explains the issue here but doesn't provide a solution.
https://keepa.com/#!discuss/t/pages-in-product-finder-request/13027/2

I want to retrieve all the results as much shown in the above message. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Keepa gave me a solution but still I am not cleared. I am not able to get the current sales rank on product object. If some one can help me to trance out then my problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

After talking to Jessica from keepa I got a way to get all the results. She told me to use a sort on sales rank ASC while calling product finder API and check the last retrieved ASIN Sales Rank and then use filter on Current Sales Rank. Keepa guide me to use CSV for current sales rank but results couldn't map.
Now the problem was from where can I get the sales rank then after a long way search I found my answer.
Here it is:

> I've used the stats array inside of product object to get the sales
> rank data.
>
> products = api.query(asins, offers=20, stats=90, history=0, rating=1)
> stats = product['stats'] currentRank = stats['current'][3]
> average30Rank = stats['avg30'][3] average90Rank = stats['avg90'][3]
> average180Rank = stats['avg180'][3]

In apps script the parsing would be like that

var currentSalesRank = data.products[0].stats.current[3];